# WordPress JS Modules problems

Tags: javascript, wordpress, npm, build, module

I'm doing a course of Wordpress programming, and I getting a totally no-sense problem... In file index.js (which is in theme folder src), I'm adding new modules which later is compiled by NPM. And the problem is that for example if I initiate **MobileMenu** class in first, **MyNotes** and **Search** classes don't **works anymore**, it feels like something breaks the code, because even the **alert()** doesn't works... I tried to look for code which can break each-other or something like that, but no luck... Can someone help me solve this problem? Thanks!

index.js

```
import "../css/style.scss"

// Our modules / classes
import HeroSlider from "./modules/HeroSlider"
import GoogleMap from "./modules/GoogleMap"
import Search from "./modules/Search"
import MyNotes from "./modules/MyNotes"
import MobileMenu from "./modules/MobileMenu"

// Instantiate a new object using our modules/classes
const mobileMenu = new MobileMenu()
const myNotes = new MyNotes()
const search = new Search()
const heroSlider = new HeroSlider()
const googleMap = new GoogleMap()
```

MobileMenu.js

```
class MobileMenu {
  constructor() {
    this.menu = document.querySelector(".site-header__menu")
    this.openButton = document.querySelector(".site-header__menu-trigger")
    this.events()
  }

  events() {
    this.openButton.addEventListener("click", () => this.openMenu())
  }

  openMenu() {
    this.openButton.classList.toggle("fa-bars")
    this.openButton.classList.toggle("fa-window-close")
    this.menu.classList.toggle("site-header__menu--active")
  }
}

export default MobileMenu
```

HeroSlider.js

```
import Glide from "@glidejs/glide"

class HeroSlider {
  constructor() {
    if (document.querySelector(".hero-slider")) {
      // count how many slides there are
      const dotCount = document.querySelectorAll(".hero-slider__slide").length

      // Generate the HTML for the navigation dots
      let dotHTML = ""
      for (let i = 0; i < dotCount; i++) {
        dotHTML += `<button class="slider__bullet glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=${i}"></button>`
      }

      // Add the dots HTML to the DOM
      document.querySelector(".glide__bullets").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", dotHTML)

      // Actually initialize the glide / slider script
      var glide = new Glide(".hero-slider", {
        type: "carousel",
        perView: 1,
        autoplay: 3000
      })

      glide.mount()
    } 
  }
}

export default HeroSlider
```

MyNotes.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class MyNotes {
    constructor() {
        this.events();
    }

    events() {
        $(".delete-note").on("click", this.deleteNote.bind(this));
        $(".edit-note").on("click", this.editNote.bind(this));
        $(".update-note").on("click", this.updateNote.bind(this));
    }

    editNote(e) {
        var thisNote = $(e.target).parents("li");
        if (thisNote.data("state") == "editable") {
            this.makeNoteReadOnly(thisNote);
        } else {
            this.makeNoteEditable(thisNote);
        }
    }

    makeNoteEditable(thisNote) {
        thisNote.find(".edit-note").html('<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cancel');
        thisNote.find(".note-title-field, .note-body-field").removeAttr("readonly").addClass("note-active-field");
        thisNote.find(".update-note").addClass("update-note--visible");
        thisNote.data("state", "editable");
    }

    makeNoteReadOnly(thisNote) {
        thisNote.find(".edit-note").html('<i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit');
        thisNote.find(".note-title-field, .note-body-field").attr("readonly", "readonly").removeClass("note-active-field");
        thisNote.find(".update-note").removeClass("update-note--visible");
        thisNote.data("state", "readonly");
    }

    updateNote(e) {
        var thisNote = $(e.target).parents("li");
        var updatedPost = {
            'title': thisNote.find(".note-title-field").val(),
            'content': thisNote.find(".note-body-field").val()
        }
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: (xhr) => {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', JSData.nonce);
            },
            url: JSData.root_url + '/wp-json/wp/v2/note/' + thisNote.data('id'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: updatedPost,
            success: () => { 
                this.makeNoteReadOnly(thisNote);
            },
            error: (response) => { 
                console.log("Error");
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }

    deleteNote(e) {
        var thisNote = $(e.target).parents("li");
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: (xhr) => {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', JSData.nonce);
            },
            url: JSData.root_url + '/wp-json/wp/v2/note/' + thisNote.data('id'),
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: () => { 
                thisNote.slideUp();
            },
            error: (response) => { 
                console.log("Error");
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }
}

export default MyNotes;
```

Search.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class Search {

    constructor() {
        this.addSearchHTML();
        this.resultsDiv = $("#search-overlay__results");
        this.openButton = $(".js-search-trigger");
        this.closeButton = $(".search-overlay__close");
        this.searchOverlay = $(".search-overlay");
        this.searchField = $("#search-term");
        this.events();
        this.isOverlayOpen = false;
        this.typingTimer;
        this.isSpinnerVisible = false;
        this.previousValue;
    }

    events() {
        this.openButton.on("click", this.openOverlay.bind(this));
        this.closeButton.on("click", this.closeOverlay.bind(this));
        $(document).on("keydown", this.keyPressDispatcher.bind(this));
        this.searchField.on("keyup", this.typingLogic.bind(this));
    }


    //Methods 
    openOverlay() {
        this.searchOverlay.addClass("search-overlay--active");
        $("body").addClass("body-no-scroll");
        this.searchField.val('');
        setTimeout(() => this.searchField.focus(), 301);
        this.isOverlayOpen = true;
        return false;
    }

    closeOverlay() {
        this.searchOverlay.removeClass("search-overlay--active");
        $("body").removeClass("body-no-scroll");
        this.isOverlayOpen = false;
    }
    
    keyPressDispatcher(e) {
        // S key
        if (e.keyCode == 83 && !this.isOverlayOpen && !$("input, textarea").is(':focus')) {
            this.openOverlay();
        // ESC key
        } else if (e.keyCode == 27 && this.isOverlayOpen) {
            this.closeOverlay();
        }
    }

    typingLogic() {
        if (this.searchField.val() != this.previousValue) {
            clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);
            if (this.searchField.val()) {
                if (!this.isSpinnerVisible) {
                    this.resultsDiv.html('<div class="spinner-loader"></div>');
                    this.isSpinnerVisible = true;
                }
                this.typingTimer = setTimeout(this.getResults.bind(this), 1500);
            } else {
                this.resultsDiv.html('');
                this.isSpinnerVisible = false;
            }
            this.previousValue = this.searchField.val();
        }
    }

    getResults() {
        $.getJSON(JSData.root_url + '/wp-json/university/v1/search?term=' + this.searchField.val() , (results) => {
            this.resultsDiv.html(`
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="one-third">
                    <h2 class="search-overlay__section-title">General Information</h2>
                    ${results.generalInfo.length ? '<ul class="link-list min-list">' : `<p>No results...</p>`}
                      ${results.generalInfo.map(item => `<li><a href="${item.permalink}">${item.title}</a> ${item.type == 'post' ? `by ${item.authorName}` : ''}</li>`).join('')}
                    ${results.generalInfo.length ? '</ul>' : ''}
                  </div>
                  <div class="one-third">
                    <h2 class="search-overlay__section-title">Programs</h2>
                    ${results.programs.length ? `<ul class="link-list min-list">` : `<p>No results... <a href="${JSData.root_url}/programs">See all programs...</a></p>`}
                      ${results.programs.map(item => `<li><a href="${item.permalink}">${item.title}</a></li>`).join('')}
                    ${results.programs.length ? '</ul>' : ''}
                    <h2 class="search-overlay__section-title">Professors</h2>
                    ${results.professors.length ? `<ul class="professor-cards">` : `<p>No results... <a href="${JSData.root_url}/professors">See all professors...</a></p>`}
                      ${results.professors.map(item => `
                        <li class="professor-card__list-item">
                          <a class="professor-card" href="${item.permalink}">
                            <img style="float: left; width: 200px; height: 200px; object-fit: cover;" class="professor-card__image" src="${item.image}">
                            <span class="professor-card__name">${item.title}</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                      `).join('')}
                    ${results.professors.length ? '</ul>' : ''}
                  </div>
                  <div class="one-third">
                    <h2 class="search-overlay__section-title">Campuses</h2>
                    ${results.campuses.length ? `<ul class="link-list min-list">` : `<p>No results... <a href="${JSData.root_url}/campuses">See all campuses...</a></p>`}
                      ${results.campuses.map(item => `<li><a href="${item.permalink}">${item.title}</a></li>`).join('')}
                    ${results.campuses.length ? '</ul>' : ''}
                    <h2 class="search-overlay__section-title">Events</h2>
                    ${results.events.length ? `` : `<p>No results... <a href="${JSData.root_url}/events">See all events...</a></p>`}
                      ${results.events.map(item => `
                        <div class="event-summary">
                          <a class="event-summary__date t-center" href="${item.permalink}">
                            <span class="event-summary__month">${item.month}</span>
                            <span class="event-summary__day">${item.day}</span>
                          </a>
                          <div class="event-summary__content">
                            <h5 class="event-summary__title headline headline--tiny"><a href="${item.permalink}">${item.title}</a></h5>
                            <p>${item.description}<a href="${item.permalink}" class="nu gray">Learn more</a></p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      `).join('')}
                  </div>
                </div>
            `);
            this.isSpinnerVisible = false;
        }); 
    }

    addSearchHTML() { $("body").append(`
    <div class="search-overlay">
      <div class="search-overlay__top">
        <div class="container">
          <i class="fa fa-search search-overlay__icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <input type="text" class="search-term" placeholder="What are you looking for?" id="search-term" autocomplete="off">
          <i class="fa fa-window-close search-overlay__close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="search-overlay__results"></div>
      </div>
    </div>`);
    }

}

export default Search
```

GoogleMap.js

```
(function( $ ) {

/**
 * initMap
 *
 * Renders a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
 *
 * @date    22/10/19
 * @since   5.8.6
 *
 * @param   jQuery $el The jQuery element.
 * @return  object The map instance.
 */
function initMap( $el ) {

    // Find marker elements within map.
    var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

    // Create gerenic map.
    var mapArgs = {
        zoom        : $el.data('zoom') || 16,
        mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], mapArgs );

    // Add markers.
    map.markers = [];
    $markers.each(function(){
        initMarker( $(this), map );
    });

    // Center map based on markers.
    centerMap( map );

    // Return map instance.
    return map;
}

/**
 * initMarker
 *
 * Creates a marker for the given jQuery element and map.
 *
 * @date    22/10/19
 * @since   5.8.6
 *
 * @param   jQuery $el The jQuery element.
 * @param   object The map instance.
 * @return  object The marker instance.
 */
function initMarker( $marker, map ) {

    // Get position from marker.
    var lat = $marker.data('lat');
    var lng = $marker.data('lng');
    var latLng = {
        lat: parseFloat( lat ),
        lng: parseFloat( lng )
    };

    // Create marker instance.
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : latLng,
        map: map
    });

    // Append to reference for later use.
    map.markers.push( marker );

    // If marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow.
    if( $marker.html() ){

        // Create info window.
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: $marker.html()
        });

        // Show info window when marker is clicked.
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open( map, marker );
        });
    }
}

/**
 * centerMap
 *
 * Centers the map showing all markers in view.
 *
 * @date    22/10/19
 * @since   5.8.6
 *
 * @param   object The map instance.
 * @return  void
 */
function centerMap( map ) {

    // Create map boundaries from all map markers.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    map.markers.forEach(function( marker ){
        bounds.extend({
            lat: marker.position.lat(),
            lng: marker.position.lng()
        });
    });

    // Case: Single marker.
    if( map.markers.length == 1 ){
        map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );

    // Case: Multiple markers.
    } else{
        map.fitBounds( bounds );
    }
}

// Render maps on page load.
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.acf-map').each(function(){
        var map = initMap( $(this) );
    });
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: is the console showing up errors? also, you said you tried to `alert` something, where was it?

Comment: Thanks!!! I was forgot about Console, got some errors like null exception, fixed, and all good.